# Creating Variable Table Name in SQL through Java?

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to make a variable Table name through Java.

My code is :

```
public void createTable(String tableName){

    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE '"+tableName+"'" +
                   "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
                   " username VARCHAR(255), " + 
                   " pass VARCHAR(255), " + 
                   " age INTEGER, " + 
                   " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))");

    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}
```

It gives me a syntax error saying:

Incorrect syntax near 'VariableTableNameIChose'.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `tableName+"'" ` - Space is missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be one of 2 things or the combination of both.

Maybe the single quotes around the table name are not valid in your database. So do like this:

```
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE "+tableName+" " +
               "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
               " username VARCHAR(255), " + 
               " pass VARCHAR(255), " + 
               " age INTEGER, " + 
               " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))");
```

Or maybe you need a spaces between the table name and the `(` following after:

```
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    //                                              v this one was missing
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE '"+tableName+"' " +
               "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
               " username VARCHAR(255), " + 
               " pass VARCHAR(255), " + 
               " age INTEGER, " + 
               " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked! (The first solution)

Answer (score 1):

The table name is an identifier. Identifiers do not use single quotes (in standard SQL).

```
"CREATE TABLE '"+tableName+"' "
```

Will result in

```
CREATE TABLE 'foobar'
```

which is invalid SQL. You need to remove the single quotes:

```
"CREATE TABLE "+tableName+" " + ...
```

As the table name is apparently a user input, you might actually want to use quoted identifiers (although this is in general a bad idea). Identifiers are quoted using *double quotes* in the SQL standard:

```
"CREATE TABLE \""+tableName+"\" " + ...
```